# Invalid ForeignKeyAttribute name with Entity Framework in code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following models

```
public class Team
{
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Comapny")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Company` class:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a new migration I get the following error

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CompanyId' on type
>   'ReportsEngine.Areas.Test.Models.User' is not valid. The navigation
>   property 'Comapny' was not found on the dependent type
>   'ReportsEngine.Areas.Test.Models.User'. The Name value should be a
>   valid navigation property name.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure is "Comapny" and not "Company"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a typo, Company instead of Comapany

```
[ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`[ForeignKey("Comapny")]` indicates that the property to use for the foreign key to the `Company` table should be `Comapny`.

The error is because you have not defined a `Comapny` property on the `Company` table.

Add the following to the `Company` table:

```
public int Comapny { get; set; }
```

Obviously it may be better to prefix it with `Id` just to show it is that type of field.

Or you could omit the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to let Entity Framework code first add one for you.